# Optaplanner Execution Server employee rostering example: Time slot is not being filled in the best solution

Tags: drools, optaplanner, kie, drools-kie-server

I was following ad litteram the following tutorial on [employee rostering](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_decision_manager/7.0/html/creating_and_solving_the_employee_roster_problem_for_red_hat_business_optimizer_using_decision_central/) from RedHat and everything is fine [until the end](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_decision_manager/7.0/html/creating_and_solving_the_employee_roster_problem_for_red_hat_business_optimizer_using_decision_central/wb-employee-rostering-solver-configuration-proc#wb-employee-rostering-register-solver-proc) when I am retrieving the best solution to the problem.

The solution does not include the values for the `endTime` and `startTime` in the `timeslot` tag.

Sample result below:

```
:
:
        <shiftList>
            <requiredSkill>
                <name>speaking</name>
            </requiredSkill>
            <timeslot>
                <endTime/>
                <startTime/>
            </timeslot>
        </shiftList>
        <shiftList>
            <requiredSkill>
                <name>writing</name>
            </requiredSkill>
            <timeslot>
                <endTime/>
                <startTime/>
            </timeslot>
        </shiftList>
:
:
```

I am using drools-wb (7.9.0.Final) on docker: `docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 8001:8001 -v /path/to/my/data/folder:/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/.niogit:Z --name drools-workbench jboss/drools-workbench-showcase:latest`

And KIE server (7.9.0.Final), also on docker: `docker run -p 8180:8080 --name kie-server --link drools-workbench:kie_wb jboss/kie-server-showcase:latest`

Anyone experiencing the same issue?

Comment: I've [created an issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-1215).

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the shiftAssignmentList not being properly constructed when sending the unsolved example to the solver. 
The following sections replace < shiftAssignmentList/> :

```
  <shiftAssignmentList>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
        <shift reference="../../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
        <shift reference="../../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[3]"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
    <employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
        <shift reference="../../../shiftList/employeerostering.employeerostering.Shift[2]"/>
    </employeerostering.employeerostering.ShiftAssignment>
  </shiftAssignmentList>
```